# AWS S3 EventNotification to SNS Topic on a Bucket not Created with (CDK, Python)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, sdk, amazon-sns

I am trying to create a notification---whenever an object is created in a folder under an S3-Bucket this should send a notification to an SNS-Topic. However, with the code below I don't get any error and no notification created either. I suppose some kind of binding the eventNotification to a bucket is missing? Can anyone help?

```
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_s3 as s3,
    aws_sns as sns,
    aws_s3_notifications as _s3_notifications,
    core as cdk
)

from aws_cdk import core


class CdkCodeStack(cdk.Stack):
def __init__(self, scope: cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
    super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
    



 # Create S3 Bucket 
    
account_id = core.Aws.ACCOUNT_ID
my_bucket = s3.Bucket(self, id='my-bucket-id', bucket_name='my-bucket')
    
    


 # Create SNS Topics named 'landing' and 'export'

sns_topic_landing = sns.Topic(self,id='sns_topic_landing_id', topic_name='sns_topic_landing')
sns_topic_export = sns.Topic(self,id='sns_topic_export_id', topic_name='sns_topic_export')
```

#send notifications to sns_topic_landing when an object is added to S3 Bucket folder = my-bucket/landing

```
 sns_destination_topic = _s3_notifications.SnsDestination(sns_topic_landing)
```

Comment: Please edit the code so that it does match with the code that you have there... `_scope (?)=` certainly isn't proper Python

Comment: I removed the part with the binding. It was just a question, if the code didn't work while it needed binding the EventNotification to the bucket. like in this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_s3_notifications/SnsDestination.html